# Swapping letters in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to swap letters in a string (DNA strand) using Ruby and the following rules:

- `'A'` is replaced by `'T'`
- `'T'` is replaced by `'A'`
- `'C'` is replaced by `'G'`
- `'G'` is replaced by `'C'`

For example, `'ACGTA'` should become `'TGCAT'`.

I have only got this far:

```
def DNA_strand(dna)    
  dna.tr!('A', 'T')    
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were quite close:

```
dna.tr('ATCG', 'TAGC')   # => "TGCAT"
```

See [ruby-doc.org on tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-tr):

> Returns a copy of `str` with the characters in `from_str` replaced by the 
>   corresponding characters in `to_str`.

Use `tr!` the same way if you want to modify your string in-place.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realise you could do that.